# Count of unique column values from large CSV file using Python or php

Tags: python, parsing, csv

I have a Csv File That Is 217gb, how can I get the count of unique column values using python or php script without timeout?

Comment: As @plsnoban mentioned, processing this huge files will (by the nature of the size) take a long time

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by timeout, for big files like this it will always take a long time.

```
tokens = {}
with open("your.csv") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        columns = line.split(',')
        # Where idx is your desired column index
        if columns[idx] not in tokens:
            tokens[columns[idx]] = 0
        else:
            tokens[columns[idx]] += 1

print tokens
```

This loads the file line by line, so your compute doesn't crash from loading the whole 217 Gb into ram. You can try this first to see if the dictionary fits in your computer's memory. Otherwise you might wanna consider splitting the files to smaller chunks in a divide and conquer approach.

Answer (score -1):

You could try to increase the `field_size_limit`

```py
import csv
csv.field_size_limit(1000000000)

r = csv.reader(open('doc.csv', 'rb'))

for row in r:
    print(row)  # do the processing
```